# Import doesn't work when name doesn't start with capital letter

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

After transpiling this code doesn't work

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import firstLow from './moniesApp.js';
```

ReactDOM.render(<firstLow />, document.getElementById('content'));

but this does

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FirstHigh from './moniesApp.js';
```

ReactDOM.render(<FirstHigh />, document.getElementById('content'));

in first case babel produces

```
_reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement('firstLow', null), document...
```

and on page there is an empty `<firstLow data-reactroot><firstLow/>` element rendered.

And in second case

```
_reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(_moniesApp2.default, null), document...
```

and it works. My component is rendered.

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What's going on?

This is a convention in JSX/React. Lower case names are converted to strings (tags), capitalized names are resolved as variables (components).

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component):

> #### Caveat:
>
> Always start component names with a capital letter.
>
> For example, `<div />` represents a DOM tag, but `<Welcome />`
>   represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.

Comment: Thanks. I lost at least 4 hours on it.

Answer (score 7):

In React, `Component` names start with capital letters. Lower-case JSX tags represent literal HTML tags. **This is part of the React specification**.

This is why `<foo>` is translated to `createElement('foo')`, while `<Foo>` yields `createElement(module.Foo)`.

You should name your components with capital letters. Not much else to do.

Comment: Felix Kling answered 13 seconds earlier, so I accepted his answer. But thanks!